# create a free body diagram with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new in TikZ (but not in LaTeX).
I am trying to create the following free body diagram.
[image]

Here is my effort so far (nothing special:-!)).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[lightgray, very thick] (0,0)rectangle (3,0.5);
\draw[->, thick](0,-1)--(0,0);
\draw[->, thick](1,-1)--(1,0);
\draw[->, thick](2,-1)--(2,0);
\draw[->, thick](3,-1)--(3,0);
\draw[->, thick](0,1.25)--(0,0.5);
\draw[->, thick](1,1.25)--(1,0.5);
\draw[->, thick](2,1.25)--(2,0.5);
\draw[->, thick](3,1.25)--(3,0.5);
\draw[->,very thick](1.5,0)--(1.5,-2);
\node at (2,-2.3) {$w=mg$};
\node at (2,1.6) {$P_{\rm{atm}}$};
\node at (2,-1.4) {$P_{\rm{gas}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

a) How can achieve this shady gray effect?
b) How can I modify the arrow heads?
c) How can I modify the perimeter of the rectangle (make it visible, black and thick)?

I have to add that I work with exam document class, `\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}`.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the world of TikZ. There is a library `shadings`, which you can use. There is also a library for the arrows (`arrows`) and the rectangle can be controlled by its properties `draw` and `line width`.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually aware of the arrows library. But with the exam class I got error messages. May be I did something wrong.

Comment: Try `\tikzset{>={stealth}}`.

Comment: I got no error with `exam` class, so you have to post a MWE.

Comment: Ok, thanks again! I did something wrong probably. I will check it again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One version of a shady gray effect is applying a radial shading to the picture. That can be done setting the `inner color` and `outer color` properties (no library required).

For the arrow tips you can use the library `arrows` and `\tikzset{>={stealth}}`. Last but not least you can apply keys such as `thick` etc. to your `\filldraw` macro. Maybe you want to have a look at the property `line width`.

[image: your picture]

*Update:* Following the great suggestion by JLDiaz in the comments you probably want to replace the `inner color`/`outer color` approach with the more appropriate (for rectangles) `left color=gray, right color=gray, middle color=white`.

[image: picture 2]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{>={stealth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[inner color=white,outer color=lightgray, thick] (0,0)rectangle (3,0.5);
\draw[->, thick] (0,-1)--(0,0);
\draw[->, thick](1,-1)--(1,0);
\draw[->, thick](2,-1)--(2,0);
\draw[->, thick](3,-1)--(3,0);
\draw[->, thick](0,1.25)--(0,0.5);
\draw[->, thick](1,1.25)--(1,0.5);
\draw[->, thick](2,1.25)--(2,0.5);
\draw[->, thick](3,1.25)--(3,0.5);
\draw[->,very thick](1.5,0)--(1.5,-2);
\node at (2,-2.3) {$W=mg$};
\node at (2,1.6) {$P_{\rm{atm}}$};
\node at (2,-1.4) {$P_{\rm{gas}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that a cylindrical shade is more akin to the OP picture. You can achieve it with `\filldraw[left color=gray, right color=gray, middle color=white, thick]`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX You're welcome ;)

Comment: @TeXnician: Thank you very much for the nice answer!